# Problema com gráfico c#

Tags: c#, desempenho, arduino, gráfico

Bom dia galera, estou desenvolvendo um programa em que deve ser plotado vários gráficos de linha(x,y) na tela, o eixo y corresponde a porta serial onde está conectada um Arduino UNO. Como exemplo, eu preciso de um gráfico onde eu tenha 6000 pontos desenhados em 20 segundos(cerca de 3.333 ms cada novo ponto). O problema é que para desenhar os 6000 pontos o programa está demorando cerca de 35 segundos. Segue chamada do controle graphControl1 que desenha o gráfico.

```
private void timerDRAW_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //timerDRAW com intervalo de 3 ms
    SerialCOM.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialCOM_DataReceived);
}

private void SerialCOM_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (SerialCOM.IsOpen)
    {
        SerialPort sData = (SerialPort)sender;
        {
            string RxString = sData.ReadLine();
            bool result = int.TryParse(RxString, out int data);
            if (result)
            {
                var atualdata = 5.0f * data / 1023.0f;
                graphControl1.AddValue(atualdata, atualdata, atualdata, atualdata);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Já tentei várias modificações no código. Recebi dicas que o método DataReceived pode ser otimizado para melhorar o desempenho do gráfico, mas não estou conseguindo implementar outra solução.

Não sei se somente essas informações são suficientes para resolver meu problema pois sou iniciante. O controle graphControl é um pouco extenso por isso não estarei anexando, mas se alguém tiver disponibilidade em ajudar eu posso enviar o código. Valeu galera !!

EDIT: Estou upando o código do controle graphControl para análise

```
public class GraphControl : Control
{
    #region DECLARAÇAO DE VARIAVEIS GLOBAIS

    int contador = 0;
    private int _minValue = 0;
    private int _maxValue = 10;
    private int _dataCount = 6000;
    private List<float> _values1 = new List<float>();
    private List<float> _values2 = new List<float>();
    private List<float> _values3 = new List<float>();
    private List<float> _values4 = new List<float>();

    #endregion

    public int MinValue
    {
        get => _minValue;
        set
        {
            _minValue = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int MaxValue
    {
        get => _maxValue;
        set
        {
            _maxValue = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int DataCount
    {
        get => _dataCount;
        set
        {
            _dataCount = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public GraphControl()
    {
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(498, 264);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    public void AddValue(float value1, float value2, float value3, float value4)
    {
        _values1.Add(value1);
        _values2.Add(value2);
        _values3.Add(value3);
        _values4.Add(value4);
        contador++;
        if (contador == 4)
        {
            Invalidate();
            contador = 0;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        var wid = (float)Width / (float)_dataCount;
        var total = 5;

        //-----------------------------------------1--------------------------------------------------------------------

        var lastPoint1 = new PointF(0F, (float)(2 * Height / 5) * 0.5F);
        var lastPoint2 = new PointF(0F, (float)(Height / 2));
        var lastPoint3 = new PointF(0F, (float)(7 * Height / 10));
        var lastPoint4 = new PointF(0F, (float)(9 * Height / 10));
        PointF newPoint1 = new PointF();
        PointF newPoint2 = new PointF();
        PointF newPoint3 = new PointF();
        PointF newPoint4 = new PointF();

        var idInit = _values1.Count - _dataCount;

        if (idInit < 0)
            idInit = 0;

        for (int i = idInit, a = 0; i < _values1.Count; i++, a++)
        {
            var value = (float)(_values1[i]);
            var porcent = value / total;

            if (porcent > 1) porcent = 1;
            var hg = porcent * (2 * Height / 5);

            newPoint1.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            if (porcent >= 1) newPoint1.Y = 2 * Height / 5 - hg;
            else newPoint1.Y = 2 * Height / 5 - hg - 1;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint1, newPoint1);

            lastPoint1 = newPoint1;

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            value = (float)(_values2[i]);
            porcent = value / total;

            hg = porcent * (Height / 5);

            newPoint2.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            newPoint2.Y = 3 * Height / 5 - hg;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint2, newPoint2);

            lastPoint2 = newPoint2;

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            value = (float)(_values3[i]);
            porcent = value / total;

            hg = porcent * (Height / 5);

            newPoint3.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            newPoint3.Y = 4 * Height / 5 - hg;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint3, newPoint3);

            lastPoint3 = newPoint3;

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            value = (float)(_values4[i]);
            porcent = value / total;

            hg = porcent * (Height / 5);

            newPoint4.X = (a + 1) * wid;

            newPoint4.Y = Height - hg -1;

            using (var p = new Pen(Color.Lime, 0.1f)) e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, lastPoint4, newPoint4);

            lastPoint4 = newPoint4;
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Na hora de enviar os valores para o graphControl estou usando os 4 valores iguais, mas é somente uma situação de teste.
Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: Nada neste código indica qualquer problema (que dê para identificar).

Comment: vish cara, vou postar o código do controle graphControl e se possível da uma olhada para mim, por favor.

Comment: Gostaria que saber qual a performance de realizar o método "Invalidate()" somente uma vez depois da carga dos dados.

Comment: Estou usando o método Invalidate( ) a cada 4 chamadas do método AddValue( ) para conseguir produzir um efeito do gráfico correndo na tela, preciso atualizar os dados na tela a todo instante. Se eu usar o Invalidate( ) em todas as chamadas do AddValue( ) o programa fica lento, os botões travam e se eu usar somente uma vez depois da carga de dados eu não consigo produzir o efeito que desejo.

Comment: O efeito seria mais ou menos como um Sismógrafo. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cSlxPeqHA8

Comment: não dá pra saber o que realmente está acontecendo, minha tentativa inicial seria verificar se a cada adição, ele não está desenhando todo o gráfico novamente (`idInit=0`), deveria desenhar apenas a parte que foi adicionada, ou limitar o desenho só em um tamanho específico na tela...

Comment: Felipe, imaginei que era necessidade, mas meu comentário foi para identificar se o gargalo está na camada de apresentação. Você ainda tem os "Invalidates()" dos gets Min, Max e Count.

Comment: Tenho integração com Arduino e eu faço posts diretamente em um micro serviço, fazendo consumo dele pelas aplicações, distribuídas, assíncronamente. Pode ser uma saída..

Comment: Entendi Andre, eu comentei os Invalidates( ) dos gets Min, Max e Count e deixei somente um Invalidate( ) depois da carga de dados, mas mesmo assim o programa ainda demora cerca de 30 segundos para atingir os 6000 pontos. Seria então um problema na camada de apresentação?

Answer (score 2):

Profile de código é o caminho que sugiro.
Use o [ClrProfile](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273) que permitirá coletar o trace de execução e com isto permitir ver onde exatamente ocorrem os gargalos.
Minha segundo sugestão. Faça um log instrumentando o código com os tempos de execução de cada trecho envolvido ([How do I measure how long a function is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10107640/47733)). Assim você vai ver onde os tempos estão sendo gastos.

Comment: valeu amigo, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: O histogram do clrProfile mostra o System.Drawing.Pen com 91%. Seria então a forma de desenhar o gargalo?

Comment: Não sou da área gráfica, mas se assim é mostrado, deve ser. Já faz tempo, mas quando montei gráficos usando C#, usei [Microsoft Chart Controls for .NET Framework](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61) e não tive problemas de desempenho.